# How to communicate among two callbacks?

Tags: haskell

AS an introduction to the language, I am writing a simple sound recorder, using [sdl2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sdl2-2.2.0/docs/SDL-Audio.html) and [wave](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wave-0.1.4/docs/Codec-Audio-Wave.html)

SDL is successfully calling my audio callback. Trouble is, I have no idea how to write those bytes to a file. The audio callback is of type

```
openDeviceCallback :: forall actualSampleType. AudioFormat actualSampleType -> IOVector actualSampleType -> IO ()
```

so I don't get a `Handle` parameter here. On the other hand, the wave write callback is of type

```
Handle -> IO ()
```

which doesn't indicate what is to be written. Please help with simple code suggestions and materials for reading.

Comment: Please always link to the concrete APIs you're working, with, i.e. in this case http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sdl2-2.2.0/docs/SDL-Audio.html and https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wave-0.1.4/docs/Codec-Audio-Wave.html, or what? — Generally speaking, you don't want “callbacks communicating with each other”. Those “file callbacks” aren't really understood as callbacks at all, merely as exception brackets. Just put the audio-recorder entirely within that bracket. That's of  course a bit limiting; the modern alterative are pipes/[conduits](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-audio).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Still confused. Is this my "recorder": `openAudioDevice :: MonadIO m => OpenDeviceSpec -> m (AudioDevice, AudioSpec)` (audioCb is part of AudioSpec)?

Comment: "Callback" is a poor name to describe the role of the function argument to `writeWaveFile`, so whatever intuition you have about "callbacks" you should simply discard. Your program logic will work something like this: open the audio device, in the scope of the `Handle`, read some amount of data from the device and write it to the `Handle`, and then after the scope of the `Handle`, close your device. This is exactly what you would do if you were explicitly opening and closing the file, except you don't need to explicitly open or close it.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, user2407038 - thanks for the help. Took me a couple of days to realize what "in the context of" means (which is - exactly what is C). Now my first Haskell program is complete. Yey!